# How does C type syntax avoid circular definition?

Tags: c, pointers

This statement and example is from [Essential C by Nick Parlante.](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/101/EssentialC.pdf)

One nice thing about the C type syntax is that it ***avoids the circular definition problems*** which come up when a pointer structure needs to refer to itself. The following definition defines a node in a linked list. Note that no preparatory declaration of the node pointer type is necessary.

```
   struct node {
      int data;
      struct node* next;
   };
```

How does the C compiler know what is `struct node*` when it is still inside the struct node.

There is another example of circular definition, wherein a type `struct treenode*` is used before it is defined further down.

```
typedef struct treenode* Tree;
struct treenode {
    int data;
    Tree smaller, larger;   // equivalently, this line could say
                            // "struct treenode *smaller, *larger"
};
```

How does the C compiler know what is `struct treenode*` when it hasn't been defined yet.

Related SO Question: [How does C resolve circular definition when a pointer in struct points to the struct itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616232/how-does-c-resolve-circular-definition-when-a-pointer-in-struct-points-to-the-st) (This is related, it doesn't answer the "How" question).

Edit: I am assuming that C compiler is able to do this in a single pass.

Comment: implementation dependently I'd guess

Comment: Incidentally, see [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/) — TL;DR the answer is usually "no", except perhaps for function pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard stipulates in [§6.2.5 **Types** ¶28](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) (emphasis added):

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>   pointer to a character type.<sup>48)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>   compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. **All
>   pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
>   as each other.** All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
>   representation or alignment requirements.

Consequently, the C compiler knows how to handle any structure pointer type because all structure pointers must have the same representation and alignment requirements.  That applies whether you embed a `struct node *` or a `struct value *` — whether or not the compiler was previously aware of the type `struct value`.  This also helps with 'opaque types' — you can have pointers to structure types where the compiler does not know the content of the structure.

What you can't do is embed a `struct node` (rather than `struct node *`) within the definition of `struct node`.  You can embed a previously known structure type as a value within the structure.  You can also define a structure type within another:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct key_value
    {
        int key;
        char *value;
    } kv;
};
```

Unlike C++, the `struct key_value` type is available without problems of scope — it is not restricted to use in the type `struct node`.  This is not good coding practice, but it is permissible.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a pointer to an incomplete type - the size and representation of a pointer does not depend on size or representation of the pointed-to type.

It also helps that, per the language standard, that pointers to all `struct` types have the same size and representation

Comment: Hi  John Bode, could you explain a bit more on the second part of your answer. What's the same size as per the language standard?

Comment: `struct node {` tells the compiler there will be a of `struct node` defined later. `struct node *` declare a pointer to that type -- which is fine, even though `struct node` is a incomplete type at that point. It is similar to providing a function prototype long before you provide the actual function definition.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran In principle, when you have two different types `T1` and `T2`, then `T1 *` and `T2 *` can have different sizes, alignment requirements, etc. But the standard requires that if `T1` and `T2` are struct types, then their pointer types must have the same size and representation (i.e. in `struct foo *ptr;` the `ptr` variable works the same way no matter what `struct foo` is).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pointer, whose size is known by the compiler, to an instance of the struct itself but it is illegal to define a struct inside a struct of the same type in type declaration.

If you attempt to declare a `struct` rather than a `struct*`, you would get a compiler error.

Comment: Curiously, you could use `struct node { int value; struct node *next; struct key_value { int key; char *value; } x; };` defining a different structure type inside `struct node`.  What you can't do is embed a `struct node` inside the definition of `struct node` — that requires infinite storage and computers don't have that much storage.  So, change the last line to say `struct node` (twice) instead of just `struct` and you would be correct.